# How to centre align my line drawing using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

#### Problem

I am trying to put this line drawing in the center of my `canvas`, when I try to use the **moveTo(100, 400)** for the x-axis, it does not change the horizontal start position to 100. If I try the same thing with the y-axis it will move the the line along the x-axis.

I also need help with drawing the y-axis numbers 1 - 9 vertically along the y-axis it seems to only align horizontally.
EDIT!: I have manually stroked each point on the y-axis so I have the numbers on there, now I just want to know how to move the graph to center!!

#### Script

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        
        ctx.linecap = 'round';
        // draw a scale with the numbers on it
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(100, 400);             
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i+=1) {
            
             //put a stroke mark
             ctx.lineTo(100*i,400);
             ctx.lineTo(100*i,405); //markers
             ctx.lineTo(100*i,400);
             
             // write the number 10px below
             ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
             // default size is 10px
             ctx.strokeText(i, 100*i, 415);
             ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
        }    
        // draw a vertical scale with lines on it
        ctx.moveTo(0, -100);
        for (b = 0; b <= 9; b+=1) {
            
            //put a stroke mark
            ctx.lineTo(0,44.5*b);
            ctx.lineTo(5,44.5*b);
            ctx.lineTo(0,44.5*b);
            
            // write the number 10px below
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            // default size is 10px                  
       }  
       ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
       ctx.strokeText(1, 8, 365);
       ctx.strokeText(2, 8, 320.5);
       ctx.strokeText(3, 8, 276);
       ctx.strokeText(4, 8, 231.5);
       ctx.strokeText(5, 8, 187);
       ctx.strokeText(6, 8, 142.5);
       ctx.strokeText(7, 8, 98);
       ctx.strokeText(8, 8, 53.5);
       ctx.strokeText(9, 8, 9);
       ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
        ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Canvas Axis calibration</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css"/> 
        
   </head>
   <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="500"style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
       Canvas is not playing!
    </canvas>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**moveTo()** just set starting point for your line, it's not draw actual line. Use **lineTo()** for draw actual line. so **moveTo()** is **from** or where you begin and **lineTo()** is where you **go**. So starting point for x axis must be **moveTo(800, 0)**.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    lineWidth = 2,
    xNumber = 6,
    yNumber = 9,
    xCenter = c.width / 2,
    yCenter = 44.5 * yNumber + 44.5

ctx.linecap = 'round';
// draw a scale with the numbers on it
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(xCenter, yCenter);

for (i = 0; i <= xNumber; ++i) {
    //put a stroke mark
    ctx.lineTo((xCenter + (100 * i)), yCenter);
    ctx.lineTo((xCenter + (100 * i)), (yCenter + 5)); //markers
    ctx.lineTo((xCenter + (100 * i)), yCenter);
             
    // write the number 10px below
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    // default size is 10px
    ctx.strokeText(i, (xCenter + (100 * i)), (yCenter + 15));
}

ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
ctx.stroke()

// draw a vertical scale with lines on it
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(xCenter, yCenter);

for (b = 0; b <= yNumber; ++b) {
    //put a stroke mark
    if(b === 0) continue;

    ctx.lineTo(xCenter, (yCenter - (44.5 * b)));
    ctx.lineTo((xCenter - 5), (yCenter - (44.5 * b)));
    ctx.lineTo(xCenter, (yCenter - (44.5 * b)));  
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.strokeText(b, (xCenter - 15), (yCenter - (44.5 * b)));
}

ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Canvas Axis calibration</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css"/> 
        
   </head>
   <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="500"style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
       Canvas is not playing!
    </canvas>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the code, it certainly helped, finally someone that actually used full codes as an example -_- anyway it seems that the markers are not working, even if i completely remove:    ctx.lineTo(xCenter, (yCenter - (44.5 * b)));
    ctx.lineTo((xCenter - 5), (yCenter- (44.5 * b)));
    ctx.lineTo(xCenter, (yCenter - (44.5 * b))); it seems the only thing that vertical line is affected by is ctx.lineTo((c.width / 2), 400); ...anywho thanks for the help and ill see if this is acceptable

Comment: Sorry, I incidentally delete **ctx.stroke()** after second loop, I have fix the code though.

Answer (score 0):

[`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) has a method for that: [`translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate). It simply sets a coordinate-shift which is going to be applied to everything you draw afterwards:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        
ctx.linecap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

ctx.translate((1600-500)/2,0);  //             <-----------

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 400);             
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i+=1) {
  ctx.lineTo(100*i,400);
  ctx.lineTo(100*i,405);
  ctx.lineTo(100*i,400);
  ctx.strokeText(i, 100*i, 415);
}    
ctx.moveTo(0, -100);
for (var b = 0; b <= 9; b+=1) {
  ctx.lineTo(0,44.5*b);
  ctx.lineTo(5,44.5*b);
  ctx.lineTo(0,44.5*b);
  if(b<9)
    ctx.strokeText(b+1, 8, 365-44.5*b);
}  
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas Axis calibration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css"/> 
  </head>
  <body>
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="500"style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">Canvas is not playing!</canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I assumed the drawing is 500 units wide, which does not seem to be entirely correct, but you will certainly see the result of `translate()`. The effect of `translate()` can be reset with `setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` call (if you are familiar with homogeneous coordinates and transformation matrices, note it has a heavily modified order, see in docs). It is actually a matrix which can do all kinds of 2D transformations (translation, rotation, scaling, skewing), `translate()` is just a convenience function (the equivalent call probaby would be `setTransform(1,0,0,1,(1600-500)/2,0)`, but I have not tried).

Minor changes:

- added the `var`-s into the loops: otherwise variables become global ones which is usually not a problem for a loop variable like `i`, but generally considered bad practice
- reduced to a single `stroke()` and two `strokeStyle`-s. The thing is that lines, arcs and the like are drawn with the settings which are set at the very moment when you call `stroke()`, it does not matter what happened in between. So color is black for most of the time, as `strokeText()` is immediate, and color becomes that beige/whatever one just for the `stroke()`
- moved the second set of labels into the corresponding loop. I am not sure if the loop is entirely correct, as 9 labels and 9 line segments are visible, but 10 line segments are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

### Think local origins

When you get a building plan you don't get a giant sheet  of paper with the plan way in the corner because you are building in the burbs, you want to move some windows out of the summer sun, you don't redraw the plan with new coordinates for each wall.

No you get the plan that fits a small sheet, on the plan is a location and orientation. The position of the walls are fix to the local coordinates of the plan.

Same goes for drawing in 2D. You can define a box as 4 points around an origin. `[[-10,-10],[10,-10],[10,10],[-10,10]]` and when you draw it you set its location and orientation, you dont change the position of each point to the new location.

### Draw local coordinate in the world via setTransform

In the 2D API the position and orientation is set via a transform.

```
 function drawPath(x,y, points) {  // only position changes
     ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y); // set the location
     ctx.beginPath();
     for(const [x,y] of points) {
         ctx.lineTo(x,y);
     }
     ctx.stroke();
 }

 const box = [[-10,-10],[10,-10],[10,10],[-10,10]];
 drawPath(100, 100, box);
```

And with scale and rotate

```
 function drawPath(x,y,scale, rotate, points) {
     const xdx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
     const xdy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;
     ctx.setTransform(xdx, xdy, -xdy, xdx, x, y); // set the location
     ctx.beginPath();
     for(const [x,y] of points) {
         ctx.lineTo(x,y);
     }
     ctx.stroke();
 }

  drawPath(100, 100, 2, 0.5, box);
```

```js
const box = [[-10,-10],[10,-10],[10,10],[-10,10]];
const W = canvas.width;
const H = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "2opx arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
const rand = v => Math.random() * v;
drawRandom();

function drawPath(x, y,scale, rotate, points) {
    const xdx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
    const xdy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;
    ctx.setTransform(xdx, xdy, -xdy, xdx, x, y); // set the location
    ctx.fillText("Hi",0,0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(const [x,y] of points) {
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Resets so line width remains 1 px

    ctx.stroke();
 }


 function drawRandom() {
     drawPath(rand(W), rand(H), rand(2) + 0.5, rand(Math.PI * 2), box);
     setTimeout(drawRandom, 500);
 }
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width ="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

All you need is `ctx.setTransform` and maybe `ctx.transform` if you are doing rigged animation stuff. I never use `ctx.translate`, `ctx.scale`, `ctx.rotate` because they are slow, and its hard to picture just where you are, oh and did I say they are SLOW!!!!

To reset the transform (remove scale, rotation and move back to 0,0) call `ctx.resetTransform()` or `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`

And some more regarding your approach to the code.

### Granular coding

Looks like you want to draw a graph.

Manually drawing every tick, setting styles, and dozens of magic numbers and values is not going to make it much fun. Worse is that when it comes time to make changes it will take forever.

### Don't repeat

You need to think like a lazy programmer. Create functions so you dont have to do the same thing over and over.

### Define styles once and name them

For example setting the 2D context style is a pain. A drawing usually only has a few different styles, so create an object with named styles

```
const styles = {
    textHang: {
        textAlign : "center",
        textBaseline : "top",
        fillStyle: "blue",
        font: "16px Arial",
    },
};
```

And a function that will set a style

```
 const setStyle = (style, c = ctx) => Object.assign(c, style);
```

Now you can set a style

```
 const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

 setStyle(styles, styles.textHang);
 ctx.fillText("The text", 100, 100);
```

### Basic 2D point helper

You are working in 2D and 2D uses a lot of points. You will be adding multiplying, copying... 2D points over and over and over.

Reduce the typing and cover the most basic 2D needs with only 7 functions

```
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x,y});
const P2Set = (p, pAs) => (p.x = pAs.x, p.y = pAs.y, p);
const P2Copy = p => P2(p.x, p.y);
const P2Mult = (p, val) => (p.x *= val, p.y *= val, p);
const P2Add = (p, pAdd) => (p.x += pAdd.x, p.y += pAdd.y, p);
const P2Sub = (p, pSub) => (p.x -= pSub.x, p.y -= pSub.y, p);
const P2Dist = (p1, p2) => ((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5;
```

### No line? 2D API

The 2D API is great, but lacking. To just draw a line is crazy long, foo bar....

```
ctx.linecap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;            
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);             
ctx.lineTo(410, 410);
ctx.stroke();
```

No way create functions, use named styles, don't enter coordinates use points.

Some common 2D tasks as functions

```
const clear = (c = ctx) => (setPos(), c.clearRect(0,0,c.canvas.width,c.canvas.height));
const line = (p1, p2, c = ctx) => (c.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y), c.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y))
const setPos = (p, c = ctx) => p ? c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, p.x, p.y) : c.resetTransform();
const path = (p, path, c = ctx) => {
    c.setTransform(1,0,0,1,p.x,p.y);
    for(const seg of path) {  // each segment
        let first = true;
        for(const p of seg) {  // each point
            first ? (c.moveTo(p.x,p.y), first = false):(c.lineTo(p.x, p.y));
        }
    }
}
```

### Example

The following takes all the above and creates 2 Axis. It may seem like a lot extra, but as you add complexity to your drawing you quickly find you need less and less code.

```js
/* Set up the context get common values eg W,H for width and height */
const W = canvas.width;
const H = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// Helper functions will use a global ctx, or pass a 2d context as last argument
// P2 is a point. I use p to mean a point
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x,y});
const P2Set = (p, pAs) => (p.x = pAs.x, p.y = pAs.y, p);
const P2Copy = p => P2(p.x, p.y);
const P2Mult = (p, val) => (p.x *= val, p.y *= val, p);
const P2Add = (p, pAdd) => (p.x += pAdd.x, p.y += pAdd.y, p);
const P2Sub = (p, pSub) => (p.x -= pSub.x, p.y -= pSub.y, p);
const P2Dist = (p1, p2) => ((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5;
const setStyle = (style, c = ctx) => Object.assign(c, style);
const clear = (c = ctx) => (setPos(0, c), c.clearRect(0,0,c.canvas.width,c.canvas.height));
const line = (p1, p2, c = ctx) => (c.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y), c.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y))
const setPos = (p, c = ctx) => p ? c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, p.x, p.y) : c.resetTransform();
const path = (p, path, c = ctx) => {
    setPos(p,c);
    for(const seg of path) {  // each segment
        let first = true;
        for(const p of seg) {  // each point
            first ? (c.moveTo(p.x,p.y), first = false):(c.lineTo(p.x, p.y));
        }
    }
}

const styles = { // define any of the 2D context properties you wish to set
    textHang: {textAlign : "center", textBaseline : "top"},
    textLeft: {textAlign : "left", textBaseline : "middle"},
    markTextStyle: {fillStyle: "blue", font: "16px Arial"},
    markStyle: {
        strokeStyle: "black",
        lineCap: "round",
        lineWidth: 2,
    },
};
const paths = {  // Array of arrays of points. each sub array is a line segment
    markLeft: [[P2(-2, 0), P2(5, 0)]],    
    markUp: [[P2(0, 2), P2(0, -5)]],    
}

// Draw an axis from point to point, using mark to mark, lineStyle for the line
// marks is an array of names for each mark, markStyle is the style for the text marks
// markDist is the distance out (90 to the right) to put the text marks
function drawAxis(fromP, toP, mark, lineStyle, marks, markStyle, markDist) {
    const norm = P2Mult(P2Sub(P2Copy(toP), fromP), 1 / P2Dist(fromP, toP));
    const step = P2Mult(P2Sub(P2Copy(toP), fromP), 1 / (marks.length-1));
    const pos = P2Copy(fromP);
    setStyle(lineStyle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    setPos(); // without argument pos is 0,0
    line(fromP, toP);
    for(const m of marks) {
        path(pos, mark);
        P2Add(pos, step);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    P2Set(pos, fromP);
    setStyle(markStyle);
    for(const m of marks) {
        setPos(pos);
        ctx.fillText(m,-norm.y * markDist, norm.x * markDist)
        P2Add(pos, step)
    }
}

const insetW = W * 0.1; 
const insetH = H * 0.1; 
const axisText =  ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
clear();
drawAxis(
    P2(insetW, H - insetH), P2(insetW, insetH), paths.markLeft,
    styles.markStyle,
    axisText,
    {...styles.textLeft, ...styles.markTextStyle},
    -18
);
drawAxis(
    P2(insetW, H - insetH), P2(W - insetW, H - insetH), paths.markUp,
    styles.markStyle,
    axisText,
    {...styles.textHang, ...styles.markTextStyle},
    6
);
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width ="400" height="400"></canvas>
```